# React Initial Null Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am passing down state from a parent component to a container to select a collection to return, however when the object is returned from the Create Container it is initially Null and so obviously I cannot access any of the properties.

EDIT: forgot to mention that although it is initially null it does then render the full object with an information alert that "the value below was evaluated just now"

I could understand if this was an ajax request but it isn't so I am stumped.

here is the code, can anyone enlighten me?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createContainer} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import Scenes from '../imports/collections/scene.js';
import SceneUpdateForm from '../imports/components/scene_update_form6.js';

//parent stateholder
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
super();
this.state = {sceneState: 1};
  }

  incrementCount() {
    this.setState({sceneState: this.state.sceneState + 1});
  }

  decrementCount() {
    this.setState({sceneState: Math.max(1,this.state.sceneState - 1)})  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container
        sceneState={this.state.sceneState}
        incClick={this.incrementCount.bind(this)}
        decClick={this.decrementCount.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

// Child component
function ChildComponent(props){
    return (
<div>
  <button onClick={props.decClick}> Dec </button>
  <button onClick={props.incClick}> Inc </button>
    <SceneUpdateForm
      scene={props.scene}
    />
</div>
  )
}


//container
let Container = createContainer((props) => {
let doc = Scenes.findOne({sheet_no: props.sceneState});
return {
  scene: doc ? doc : null

  }
}, ChildComponent);
```

Comment: Exact error you are getting ?

Comment: `props.sceneState` instead of `props.scene`?

Comment: @JF -  I need access to the properties in the scene object (from the db) to autopopulate an update form

Comment: @superB when I try and get access to the properties in the scene object in the SceneUpdateForm component sent through the props I get an undefined error.... scene_update_form6.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sheet_no' of undefined(…) Exception from Tracker recompute function: TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
    at

Comment: I have replaced   scene: doc ? doc : null with   scene: doc ? doc : {project_ID:"" etc...} and now it works, just don't know why it is not there initially. Is this a delay in the state?